# How to operate on values with different coordinates within the same dimension?

Tags: python-xarray

When operating on different data-arrays, `xarray` is helpful enough to make sure the operation happens on values with the same coordinate.  This is often desirable, but sometimes I want to explicitly operate on values with different coordinates.  This will result in an empty `DataArray`:

```
In [275]: ds = xarray.DataArray(random.random(size=10), {"a": arange(10)}, dims=["a"])

In [274]: ds.sel(a=slice(5, None)) - ds.sel(a=slice(0, 4))
Out[274]: 
<xarray.DataArray (a: 0)>
array([], dtype=float64)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64
```

Of course, I could instead operate on the underlying `.values`, bypassing `xarray`, but is there a way to do this within the xarray API?  I realise I would have to inform xarray what coordinates should be assigned to the result, but the dimensions, unaffected coordinates, name, encoding, and attributes could still be copied over.

My *actual* use case is to find instances where two `A[i] & B[i+1]` for boolean arrays `A` and `B` with identical coordinates, such as `(A[:-1] & B[1:])`, but `xarray`s helpful alignment makes this identical to `(A & B)[1:-1]`, which has a different meaning.

But there are many possible applications:

- Taking the difference between measurements taken at different times
- Taking the difference between measurements with different lat/lons

Comment: What would you want the coordinate of the result to be? It seems a bit like you want to reject the coordinate labels and just join on location.

Comment: You could copy the DataArray, shift the coordinate, and then join? That way the old da and the new da would be 'off' by the shift

Comment: @Maximilian I realise I would need to inform the `DataArray` of the coordinate.  In this case, I do want to reject the coordinate labels, I've so far settled for (`x.variable` & `y.variable`) but regrettably that loses all the other information as well.

Comment: Yes. What do you think of the 'separate / shift / join' option? Did that make sense?

Comment: @Maximilian Vaguely, but I'm not sure what it would look like in practice.  I tried to play around with `reindex` and `assign_coords` but I'm not sure if those are the right methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One will have to do something like:

```
xarray.DataArray(a.variable - b.variable, coords=a.coords, name="Δ")
```

This still ensure that the dimensions are consistent (and will broadcast if not), but it does allow to calculate operations between values with different coordinates.  Then the `coords=` keyword is essential to tell `xarray` what the coordinates of the result should be.